# Does the new VSCODE 1.18 JS/TS auto-import work with npm-installed nodelibs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I am trying out the new auto-import feature with a JS file in a simple project.

I installed mongoose with npm and saved a new blank js file that I am editing. I expect that after I type `const Schema = mongoose.` that I should see an intellisense popup menu with mongoose nodelib suggestions and, if I select one, VSC should add an import/require statement for mongoose at the top of the file. I am seeing "Schema" in the intellisense menu, but nothing happens after I select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-imports in VS Code 1.18 cannot create `import * as X from 'Y'` style imports, only `import { x } from Y`. Support for the former is tracked by https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19630

In your example, you should be able to just start typing out `Schema` to get an auto import suggestion that adds `import { Schema } from 'mongoose'`